# How to implement a ClickListener for a button from a custom layout to use in a FragmentDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm try to set the action for ImageButton. When the DialgoFragment is called and is shown on screen, I want to preess the button and get an action. When I put my action inside that onClick in the code below it didn't work. I'm sure that's not the right way of doing it.

I'm using this class as fragment:

```
public class GeneralDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Inflate the layout to use as dialog or embedded fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, container, false);

        ImageButton mImageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
        mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = "";
                SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String yourmessage = prefs.getString("msg", null);
                if (yourmessage != null) {
                    name = prefs.getString("msg", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
                }
                ScrollTextView txt = (ScrollTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.scroll_text);
                txt.setText(name);
                txt.setTextSize(220);
                txt.startScroll();

            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

And in this activity_dialog layout I have an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_500px"/>
```

Edited: Now the action is in the class above. The error actually is in the action. I have the MainActivity where I press this send button:

```
 public void send(View view){
        EditText mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_msg);
        String MESSAGE = mEditText.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("msg", MESSAGE );
        editor.commit();


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

It calls the MessageActivity where I call the GeneralDialogFragment class which shows the ImageButton with this code:

```
DialogFragment mDialog = new GeneralDialogFragment();
    mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog TAG");
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem are you facing exactly? I have tried the same code and it is working for me.

Comment: Put your actions code here, perhaps you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, thank you guys, the problem is with the action. I didn't check tomcat :/ because I tested the code i'm using in the onClick before. But I tested in a button right inside the MessageActivity instead of using the GeneralFragmentDialog and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `v` which you've added it before, it's working without any errors:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, container, false);
        ImageButton mImageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
```